# Why include __DIR__ in the require_once?

Tags: php, autoloader

For example, I always see autoloaders called like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

What is the difference between that and the more concise

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

PHP scripts run relative to the current path (result of `getcwd()`), not to the path of their own file. Using `__DIR__` forces the include to happen relative to their own path.

To demonstrate, create the following files (and directories):

```
- file1.php
- dir/
   - file2.php
   - file3.php
```

If `file2.php` includes `file3.php` like this:

```
include `file3.php`.
```

It will work fine if you call `file2.php` directly. However, if `file1.php` *includes* `file2.php`, the current directory (`getcwd()`), will be wrong for `file2.php`, so `file3.php` cannot be included.

Answer (score 15):

The current accepted answer does not fully explain the cause of using `__DIR__` and in my opinion the answer is wrong.
I am gonna explain why do we really need this.
Suppose we have a file structure like this

```
- index.php
- file3.php -(content: hello fake world)
- dir/
   - file2.php
   - file3.php - (content: hello world)
```

If we include `file3.php` from `file2.php` and run `file2.php` directly, we will see the output `hello world`.
Now when we include `file2.php` in `index.php`, when the code will start executing and it will see `file2.php` again including `file3.php` using `include 'file3.php'`, at first the execution will look for `file3.php` in the current execution directory (which is the same directory where `index.php` is present)..Since `file3.php` is present in that directory, it will include that `file3.php` instead of `dir/file3.php` and we will see the output `hello fake world` instead of `hello world`.

If `file3.php` would not exist in the same directory, it would then include the correct `dir/file3.php` file which makes the accepted answer not valid because it states `file3.php cannot be included` which is not true. It is included.

However, here comes the necessity of using `__DIR__`. If we would use `include __DIR__ . '/file3.php'` in `file2.php`, then it would include the correct file even though another `file3.php` is present in the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

For include its possible to set some folders where PHP search automatically. When you include a file with a relative path you search in all of that folders. Its better to define the real path to prevent some errors in loading wrong files.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Then you can be sure that you load the correct file.

Comment: While this is true as well, this is not really the most important reason.

Answer (score 0):

When, for example, a file is in *C:/xampp/htdocs/projecName/originalDirectory*, the **../** path starts from the parent directory where the file is written, which, in this case, is *originalDirectory*.

If, however, this file is included somewhere else outside of the originalDirectory, then the parent directory is no longer the same, so, the path will fail.

> Conclusion: using ../ is not portable because it is relative to the current directory.

This is the reason why we use `__DIR__` as a prefix.
The `__DIR__` will "hardwire" the absolute path, which in this example is *C:/xampp/htdocs/projecName/**originalDirectory***.

Hence, regardless of where the file is called from, it will always start from ***originalDirectory*** because it has been set in stone as follows:

*C:/xampp/htdocs/projecName/**originalDirectory/**../filebeingincluded.php*
.