# I'm not able to include any other PHP files in index.php

Tags: php, html, mysql, path, include

So I am a newbie in **PHP** but I need to make an assignment, in which I have to put together a web page using **PHP** and **MYSQL**.

While I was creating my pages in **PHP** with ATOM text editor, I wanted to create the different elements of the page in separate files. For example, I created a *head.php* and a *header.php*, and I wanted to include them in the *index.php*.

No matter how I adjusted the path, I just couldn't get it to work.

I even tried:

```
-include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/head.php")
    and require()
    and The full path to the file
```

Here are some screens to help you better understand.
[image: This one shows the index.php with the including]
[image: This one shows the head.php with the path to the screen.css]

Comment: USE `ECHO` WHILE IMPORTING FILES

Comment: try `include("./head.php");` Bcz you are in same direcorty level

Comment: You have two files `head.php` one in your root and one in your includes directory but in the screenshot you show the one in the root so try like @AbdullaNilam suggested

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I just forgot to delete that one. The one I am trying to access is in the includes folder. Though before I deleted the one in my root folder, I tried your suggestion and sadly it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, Fixed My Issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code - not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your include(s) to:

```
include(__DIR__.'/head.php');
```

or (older php)

```
include (dirname(__FILE__).'/head.php');
```

Otherwise your include directive will just search for the file using your
'php include path', which might be wrong.

Have a look here:

> [How to use __dir__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir)
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.get-include-path.php