# PHP action form is not working. root of the action form shows 404 even when the file is there

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, action

It worked perfectly when the same .PHP files (the one with the form and the action one) were inside the some folder. But for security reasons I need the 'action' file outside the folder with another path.

I'm writing the code correctly (I guess):

```
action="../connect/dashboard/admin/register_dw_user.php"
```

It doesn't make sense to me, it's clearly that I'm missing something. But I don't know what.

And the connect.php file to link the MYSQL DB is working perfectly, and it's also inside the same 'connect' folder. I'm using:

```
       include '../connect/lib/connect.php';
```

That made clear that the 'connect' folder is just one above the 'public' one. But for some reason isn't working with the action form.

This is what I tried and didn't worked:

```
 action="/connect/dashboard/admin/register_dw_user.php"
 action="../connect/dashboard/admin/register_dw_user.php"
 action="../../connect/dashboard/admin/register_dw_user.php"
 action="../../../connect/dashboard/admin/register_dw_user.php"
 action="connect/dashboard/admin/register_dw_user.php"
```

Any idea? PLEASE! I need Help!

[image: screenshot form code]

[image: the file it's on the server]

[image: I just keep pulling the 404, help...]

Comment: You should always use absolute pathes...

Comment: But in this case what would be the absolute pathes.. is not the: ../../ making it absolute path?

Comment: Are you setting any rules in a htaccess file?

Comment: For files (include) use __DIR__ constant like `include __DIR__ . '/../../some/path'; `. Background: relative pathes are relative to the current working directory, which can be different from the directory in which the actual script resides.

Comment: @imposterSyndrome yes :

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: You might want to consider using [\_\_DIR\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir)

Comment: @Remy but how can i use the __DIR__ as an action in a html form?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Ok, thank you! I have a better point of this.  But how can I use the DIR as an action in a html form?

Comment: Relative URL are relative to the base URL (please search this term on the internet and read it there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use absolute paths especially when you're accessing files from different folders

**For offline usage**
This is if you are not even trying to render php,just testing if the submit button calls the right file

```
For example say your form.htm is located at [Drive]/myname/admin/data/form.htm
and your processor.php is at [SameDrive]/myname/admin/data/anotherdata/processor.php

to call that php file from htm you set your action to action="/myname/admin/data/anotherdata/processor.php"
```

**For localhost or server[if you are on server]**
usually the path is either "www/" or "www/root/"

```
say your form.htm is located at www/root/admin/data/form.htm
and your processor.php is at www/root/admin/data/anotherdata/processor.php

you can now use action="/admin/data/anotherdata/processor.php"
```

Alternatively

You could add url before the path like:

```
action="https://myurl.com/admin/data/anotherdata/processor.php"
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked..I don't know what im doing wrong..

Comment: The path can be found in properties check there....also why not move the files to the same folder so you don't have to worry about the path

Comment: Perhaps try adding the URL before the path