# Proper way to include header and functions files in PHP

Tags: php

I have my all files in public_html directory like this

```
global_assets
assets/layouts/header.php
assets/setup/env.php
order/index.php
order/info/index.php
```

Now all is working fine in order/index.php in which I am including header like

```
include '../assets/layouts/header.php';
```

Now I have tried include header in my order/info/index.php like below

```
include '../../assets/layouts/header.php';
```

Header getting included properly in this too, but its giving me error called

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '../assets/setup/env.php' in /home/myusername/public_html/assets/layouts/header.php on line 7
```

I will have many similar errors because of directory structures. I think I am not following proper way to include files so I can call it properly from any directory, sub directories without any issues. Let me know if anyone here can help me for it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: using `__DIR__` magic method before your file path. a good [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir) here to understand.

Comment: when use _DIR_ as per you in my info/index.php, its include header but I have still same issue remain for env.php which is required by header.php

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález `__DIR__` actually means "The directory of the file". Main script is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$argv[0]`

Comment: @shingo Thank you for the correction. I managed to write the exact opposite of what I had in mind... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and retrieve the root of your project in several ways, then you can always access php files from this root.

1. [environment variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

   ```
   include getenv('MY_PROJ_ROOT').'/assets/...';
   ```
2. [auto-prepend-file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

   ```
   //php.ini
   auto_prepend_file="/path/to/prepend-file.php"

   //prepend-file.php
   define('MY_PROJ_ROOT', '/path/to/project-root');

   //any other files
   include MY_PROJ_ROOT.'/assets/...';
   ```
3. [include-path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)

   ```
   //php.ini
   include-path=".:/path/to/project-root"

   //other files
   include 'assets/...';
   ```

Comment: This have solved the issue. Thanks a lot sir!