# Why the path beginning with '/' points to 'C:/'?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, document-root

I have created a site in localhost in the path `C:/xampp/htdocs/seintian.altervista.org` and then I hosted it in a hosting platform ([Altervista](https://altervista.org)).

After some months of programming in that directory I changed the root directory of the site in localhost to, simply, `C:/xampp/htdocs` because in that way I thought that I would have been able to run the site by searching `http://localhost/` and, also, to use the paths `/sub/dir/of/the/site` instead of the relative ones like `../sub/dir/of/the/site`, etc.

However, they somehow point to the path `C:/` instead of `C:/xampp/htdocs` that is the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of the Apache site (the local hosting is powered by XAMPP).

Plus, I tried to upload the server folder to Altervista, to see if there worked, but - and you can check by yourselves [here](https://seintian.altervista.org) - also there it didn't work, responding with a "file or directory not found at [...]" error.

Is it normal that `/path/to/file` points to `C:/` even if the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` constant is set to `C:/xampp/htdocs`? And, in any case, how can I make possible that paths like `/sub/dir/of/the/site` point to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, how expected?

PS: just to say, some paths in `link` elements in the `head` section of the page, point correctly to the right path, for example the assets of the page situated in `C:/xampp/htdocs/assets`. how is it possible? Does PHP just hate me? :'(

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Yes, that's normal. Paths _not_ beginning with '/' are interpreted relative to the current directory, whether they begin with '..' or not. (Fortunately, I'm pretty sure PHP doesn't hate you, though.)

Comment: yes, I know that, but they normally point to the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` path, in fact the link tags work fine...

Comment: `__DIR__` can be useful to deal with this. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir

Comment: thank you, man! I thought 'bout that, but I didn't imagined that it would have been useful if appended to the paths :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/...` points to default storage, so in your case it's `C:`.

While links in webpage `/...` links to root directory of http server (do not mix directory path with URL path, they are not the same)

So these are pointing to same location, but has different meaning:

```php
file_get_contents('/etc/dir/xampp/htdocs/assets/images/a.js');
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="/assets/images/a.js"></script>
```

---

I personally suggest to make your site portable by appending `__DIR__` to all paths that are used in PHP:

```php
// C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php
ROOT_DIR = __DIR__;

...

file_get_contents(ROOT_DIR  . '/assets/images/a.js');
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works! but will it work online, too?

Comment: @Seintian Yes, since `__DIR__` is constant of current file dir, it will work everywhere