# __DIR__ only returns part of the path in Laravel - missing one folder

Tags: localhost, laravel-8, absolute-path

I am using Laradock/Docker with apache2 webserver.

localhost is pointing to /Users/paul/Sites (normal on Mac Monterey)

I have a laravel 8 project which is located on /Users/paul/Sites/ProjectX.

In /Users/paul/Sites/ProjectX/index.php, I have echo **DIR**;

In browser, localhost/ProjectX returns /var/www/ProjectX.  Why is the "Sites" folder missing in the **DIR** constant?  Is that normal?

I am pulling my hair off... this seems so trivial but I can not find the aqnswer... please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working **exactly** as expected.

[`__DIR__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir) is meant to return the absolute directory path of the currently running script.

[Laradock](https://laradock.io/) makes use of [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to mount your "app code path" (`/Users/paul/Sites/ProjectX`) on the **host machine** into the **docker container** at this "app code path" (`/var/www/ProjectX`). This allows you to preview your app code changes immediately rather than having to *copy* over source code on each change/edit.

[`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/fee2d33ad86133bcc354d4ee856b20ab3b60add0/docker-compose.yml#L179)

```yaml
# ...
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
# ...
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
```

With that in mind, it's evident that the two environments have **separate file systems**.

When you make an HTTP request in your browser on the *host machine*, that HTTP request will be "forwarded" to a [docker container listening on that specific port](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/fee2d33ad86133bcc354d4ee856b20ab3b60add0/docker-compose.yml#L477). I.e:

```yaml
# ...
      ports:
        - "${APACHE_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${APACHE_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
# ...
```

Understanding that your HTTP request will be handled by a particular *docker container* (i.e. Apache/Nginx) rather than the *host machine*, performing an `echo __DIR__;` will result in a script's absolute **mounted** directory path based on the *docker container's file system*.