# AJAX call require_once in php not executed

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to make an piece of code that retrieves data from my mysql server and refreshes its content every second without refreshing the page.

When I execute the code below I get an error on the screen:

```
Warning: require_once(../cfg/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \php\classes\update.php on line 9

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../cfg/db.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in \php\classes\update.php on line 9
```

The path is set correctly, because when I include the file that is not going via the ajax call it works. So somehow the ajax call does not want to look into another directory. Anyone an solution for this?

`/pages/main.php`
In this file The ajax call is being initialized.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    retrieveUpdate();
})

function retrieveUpdate(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../php/classes/update.php',
        data: 'type=test',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(index){
            console.log("LOG: "+index);
            //alert(index[0]);

            setTimeout(index,1000);
        },
        timeout: 1000,
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
}
```

`/php/classes/update.php`

```
require_once('../cfg/db.php'); // folder is /php/cfg/db.php

class Update
{

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function getUpdate(){
        $db = new DB();

        if($db->databaseConnection()){
            $query_retrieve_update = $db->db_connection->prepare("SELECT update_id FROM update");
            $query_retrieve_update->execute();

            while($result_retrieve_update = $query_retrieve_update->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $json_retrieve_update[] = $result_retrieve_update;
            }
        print json_encode($json_retrieve_update);

        }
    }

}
    $update= new Update();

if(isset($_POST['type'])){
    if($_POST['type'] == 'test'){
        $update->getUpdate();
    }
}
```

`/php/cfg/db.php`

```
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "xxx");
define("DB_USER", "xxx");
define("DB_PASS", "xxx");

class DB
{
    public $db_connection = NULL;

    public function databaseConnection(){
        if($this->db_connection != NULL){
            return true;
        }else{
            try{
                $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.'', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                return true;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->errors[] = DB_CONN_FAIL;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
$db = new DB();
```

Comment: its probably a `current working directory` issue,  try instead `require_once(__DIR__.'/../cfg/db.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add `__DIR__`. for some explanation see [How to use __dir__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537477/how-to-use-dir)

```
require_once(__DIR__.'/../cfg/db.php');
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is needed in an AJAX call, but when I just use PHP it is not needed?

Comment: I think the problem isn't AJAX, for example how PHP includes are working with different levels of directory's you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444572/why-include-dir-in-the-require-once