# How to Reference File Two Directories Up, in Current File in PHP

Tags: php, html

1. List item

I have a dircetory Security in which there is a file index.html and another folder security which contains docs folder and in docs folder there is file banner.html. I want to add banner.html through  in index.html but I am not being able to understand which pathe to use.

Security-> index.html and security folder-> docs-> banner.html. I want to add banner.html in index.html. Please any Idea? I shall be very thankful for any help.

My directory and file structure is

- Security

  - index.html
  - security

    - Docs

      - banner.html

Root folder is Security with capital S and inside it are index and security with small s and security contains Docs and Docs contains banner.html and I want to add banner.html in index.html

Comment: If all your files are `.html`, what does this have to do with PHP? Also, could you please show a graphical representation of your directory structure, eg a screenshot from Explorer / Finder? ASCII art is fine too

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to take screen shots of nested folders.

Comment: If all files are html and not php then how to reference banner.html in index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that all your files are HTML however you have added the PHP tag to your comment, so my solution will be written PHP.
So if I am understanding correctly you folder structure follows:

- Security

  - Index.php
  - security

    - Docs

      - Banner.php

So in your index.php file you can place

```
<?php require __DIR__ . 'security/Docs/banner.php'; ?>
```

or

```
<?php include __DIR__ . 'security/Docs/banner.php'; ?>
```

Read more about [Require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [Include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [**DIR**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32444835/10051754)

Comment: Would be much better if you prefix those paths with `__DIR__`, just in case `index.php` is included from somewhere else

Comment: Tom Tanks for your kind response. I have elaborated my directory structure. could you please review your answer with this directory structure.

Comment: @ArslanKhan try figuring out for yourself, I will update my answer as well though mate!

Comment: @ArslanKhan No worries, if this has solved your problem can you please mark my answer as the solution.