# Link a js on a PHP

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm a Amateur programer and I need help for my web's programer subject. I'm trying to link this js but on the page show me this on the top Warning: file_get_contents(script404.js): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\villanueva-s_theme-brown_nights-\404.php on line 58

```
<?php
   $script = file_get_contents('script404.js');
   echo "<script>".$script."</script>";
?>
```

Comment: `script404.js` is in the same folder as the php that calls it? And why not just `?><script src="script404.js"></script><?...`

Comment: Well the error should be self-explanatory, the file is not located in the path the error message mentions. One question here though would be, why you want to read the file contents via PHP in the first place here, instead of letting the client request the script via URL, by using `<script src="..."></script>` …?

Comment: The error obviously says that the file does not exist in that directory.

Comment: Try my answer..

Comment: Are you still here? Or did you fix it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
echo "<script src=\"script404.js\"></script>";
```

Or, you should point to the right directory, like:

```
   $script = file_get_contents('C:/path/to/script404.js');
   echo "<script>".$script."</script>";
```

Or, I wouldn't advice you to do this, but if it is in the same directory:

```
   $script = file_get_contents('./script404.js');
   echo "<script>".$script."</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have an invalid path.

You could use `__DIR__.'/script404.js'` if this file is in the same folder as script you running.

See Evert's answer in [Why include __DIR__ in the require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444572/why-include-dir-in-the-require-once)